# How to make my 11-month-old son eat again?

Tags: infant, health, eating

My 11-month-old son stopped eating. We are giving him all the food in pureed form. But nowadays, after eating 2 to 3 spoons, he is not ready to open his mouth. Many times he is doing like vomitting. I am very much worried about him. Any helpful suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried transferring to solids instead? Small pieces of fruit?

Comment: Have you taken him to a doctor? This might be a medical problem, but this forum can't provide medical advice.

Comment: So he's eating nothing? Or is he still being breastfed as well?

Comment: This can be common at this age but as others have said you should always take him to a doctor.

Answer (score 1):

Could he be cutting teeth? I've known children this age to lose their appetite, change sleep patterns or even regress a bit when cutting teeth.

I agree with the suggestion for solids :)

However, if he starts showing signs of dehydration or weight loss, I'd make a doctor's appointment.